# MFC Excel Automation Error: Can't Close The MFC Program

Tags: excel, visual-c++, mfc

I'm developing MFC program with Excel Automation in VC++ 6.0.
I'm very new to MFC program using automation.

When I execute the program, it is opened with Excel. And I can access .xls file in the MFC program.
Here's the problem. 
For now, if I close the MFC program, Excel is closed too. But if I close the Excel first and try to close the MFC program, there's an error message saying

```
"the object invoked has disconnected from its clients.".
```

And also I can see this message in output window.

```
Warning: constructing COleException, scode = DISP_E_DISCONNECTED 
($80010108)
```

These error messages also appear when I try to open another excel file through file open button which i made in the MFC program.

I've been reading many similar questions and answers but it's hard to find "in MFC" situation.

And this is the code.

```
void CNepExcelDlg::ExcelCancel()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    if((m_ExcelFileFlage == 1) || (m_ExcelFileFlage == 1))
    {
        m_Book.Save();

        m_ExcelFlage = 0;   
        m_ExcelFileFlage = 0;
        m_Range.ReleaseDispatch();
        m_Shape.ReleaseDispatch();
        m_Shapes.ReleaseDispatch();
        m_Sheet.ReleaseDispatch();
        m_Sheets.ReleaseDispatch();
        m_Book.ReleaseDispatch();
        m_Books.ReleaseDispatch();
        m_App.Quit();
        m_App.ReleaseDispatch();
    }
}

void CNepExcelDlg::OnCancel() 
{
    // TODO: Add extra cleanup here
    int sum;

    KillTimer(ID_TIMER);
    sum = SetStop();
    if(sum != 0) SetStop();

    SetPortClose();
    ExcelCancel();

    CDialog::OnCancel();
}
```

Comment: **Anything** in MFC is hard if you don't understand the underlying system the framework abstracts. You're going to have to take a step back and learn the Windows API (and COM) first.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for your advice. I didn't have enough time so I solved it with try/catch.

Comment: That's not a solution. There's still a bug in your program, that you need to fix. Merely hiding it won't bode well.

Comment: The problem is the excel handle is no more when you try to close the application after closing the application.  You have to handle the close event of the excel application in yours to fix this issue.

Comment: Where this variable m_ExcelFileFlage is set to 1?